# A differential equation question in orthogonal trajectories

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$3x^2 - y^2 = c$$

My solution is;

$$6x - 2y{dy \over dx}=0$$

$$ {dy \over dx} = {3x \over y} $$ 
We have also a slope ${dy \over dx}= {-y \over 3x}$ But here, I guess there is something wrong..

Comment: you must solve the equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y}{3x}$

Comment: In this chapter, the equations which are given by our teacher was always seperable. But dy/dx = -y/3x is not seperable. Does it matter? Then in "orthogonal trajectories", we do not care whether the equation is seperable or not. We always solve the dy/dx whatever it is, right?

Comment: I'm so sorry, it is clearly seperable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have $\frac{dy}{y}=-\frac{1}{3}\frac{dx}{x}$
solving this we get $y(x)=\frac{C}{x^{1/3}}$
$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y}{3x}$ is seperable!